# C# 1 datagridview 2 databases where statement

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Is it possible to add data from 2 tables in 1 datagridview.

And let table 2 add information that is equal with `row[0].`

The problem is Name is in another table as the needed information but `ID's` are matching.

Table 1 got : ID,Time and some other stuff.
Table 2 got : ID,Name.

So he needs to get the `ID` from row 0 and with Table 2 He needs to get the name `WHERE ID` is equal to `Row 0`

Comment: please proivde more detail on your issue

Comment: Hope this is beter for you? what do you excatly need? @ZaidMirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to place two tables into the same datagridview.  Run a query like this..

```
Select ID, name
From Table2
Where ID IN (
                       Select Top 1
                       ID
                       Table1
                       )
```

And then use this to fill a datatable, and set that as the data source of the datagridview.

Comment: Thank you :) that where what i needed!:)

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for then you should mark this as the accepted answer (there's a grey checkmark you can click on to the left of this post).  @JorisDijkstra

Comment: This is a link to the tutorial for Stack Overflow.  I would recommend you take a few minutes to look at it as it will help you get an idea of how the website works.  http://stackoverflow.com/tour  Hope it helps @JorisDijkstra

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to mess with DataGridView, Here is simple Solution based on ADO.NET

```
string select = "SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.ID=table2.ID";
 MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection();
 MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select, c.con); //c.con is the connection string

 MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; 
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```